# why my css not finding?

Tags: node.js, express

I have attached my css file to my html file. And then i run and open page using express in node js. However, the css file does not open when i run the webserver through node js.
**html(show.ejs)**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" media="screen" />
</head>
  <body>
    <h1> Value is <%= detail %></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**node js**

```
//required npm
var express = require('express');//express 4.*

var path = require('path');

// define app
var app = express();

// set up template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


//static files
//app.use('/static', express.static('/public')); //not working
app.use('', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  //not working
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  //not working
//app.use('/public/assets', express.static('public/assets'));  //not working

app.get('/show/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('./panel/show', {
        detail: req.params.id ,
    });

//port
app.listen(3000);
```

**my project folder**

> node_modules
>
> views
>
> > panel
> >
> > > show.ejs
>
> public
>
> > assets
> >
> > > css
> > >
> > > > style.css
>
> app.js
>
> package.json

Comment: yes, but this is not worked href="assets/css/style.css"

Comment: are you getting 404?

Comment: no, css not finding.    in inspect element style.css path is "localhost:3000/show/asset/style.css"

Comment: @JavadDehhabe What is the error?

Comment: style.css not loading in page. when click href="assets/css/style.css" the page error "Cannot GET /show/assets/css/styles.css"

Comment: try href="./assets/css/style.css" or href="/assets/css/style.css"

Comment: @rijin , thank you  href="/assets/css/style.css" worked .

Comment: @JavadDehhabe give a vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By entering `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" media="screen" />` You are trying to find the `assets` folder in your out of public directory.

So, when you `/` it will find `public` directory which is statically defined in express server.

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
    <h1> Value is <%= detail %></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```